# Is it possible to resize a canvas after transferControlToOffscreen() in wasm?

Tags: javascript, webassembly, emscripten

I am cross compiling to wasm a multi-threaded rendering engine.
Upon spawning render thread we call `emscripten_pthread_attr_settransferredcanvases` which is same as calling `transferControlToOffscreen()` in JS.
In runtime a hosting JS code is required to resize the canvas to match a window size requested by the user.

For example,calling this:

```
   var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
   canvas.width = 640;
   canvas.height = 360;
```

Throws:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'width' property on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Cannot resize canvas after call to transferControlToOffscreen().
```

I know we are not allowed to call DOM on a secondary thread (worker) in wasm.I wonder if there is still a way to perform canvas resizing in runtime when rendering in worker and using offscreen framebuffer in C++ or in JavaScript?